# Create matrix positive definide

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I´m developing a code in `c++` using `openMP` to test the power of `parallelism` using `openMp`. I create the code to solve `linear system` using `Jacobi` by aproximation. Now I need to test using a big matrix.

My matrix to test is little.

$$\begin{cases}2x_1-x_2 = 1\\ x_1+2x_2=3\end{cases}$$

Now I need help because I don´t know how to create a bigger matrix like this.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a large positive definite matrix, take a random matrix $A$ and take $M=A^TA$. $M$ will then be symmetric positive semidefinite, since

- $M^T = (A^TA)^T=A^T(A^T)^T=A^TA$
- For any $x$, $x^TMx =x^TA^TAx = (Ax)^T Ax\geq 0$.

If the rank of $A$ is full, meaning $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$, then $M$ will also be positive definite.

Comment: Ok, I´m didn´t understand all, but my firs doubt is, and the values after equals?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that if you want a large positive definite matrix, take any matrix $A$ and calculate $A^TA$. The result will be positive (semi)definite.

Comment: I understand that a I need to generate a random matrix, and multiply this matrix by his transposed. Correct?

Comment: Yes. That way, you can get a positive definite $1000000\times 1000000$ matrix, if you want.

Comment: Ok but I think that you don´t understand what´s my doubt...Imagine if I want a 2 x 2 matrix. It will be generated. a, b, c, d numbers, but it isn´t a expression like in my picture. because a + b = number, c + d = othernumber

Comment: I guess this depends on what structure do you use to store the system, it certainly must be stored in some data structure and not like "something on the picture". You should state whether you want the systems to be dense or sparse (AFAIK Jacobi method is usually used in the context of sparse systems). However, if it is dense I would certainly not create a $1000000\times 1000000$ matrix in any possible way since such a matrix would eat when stored in double precision more than 7TiB of memory :-D

Answer (score 0):

Well, on a $2\times 2$ system you won't see much improvements using any parallelism :-)

Since you implement the Jacobi method, I suppose you want your matrix to be sparse. Why don't you simply take, say, a finite difference discretization of a Laplacian? You can create it in MATLAB simply as follows:

```
% 1D Laplacian:
N  = 100; % Size of the matrix
A1 = gallery('tridiag', N); % Generate the tridiag(-1,2,-1) matrix of size N

% 2D Laplacian:
I  = speye(N); % Create the sparse NxN identity matrix
A2 = kron(I, A1) + kron(A1, I);
```

You can also create a 2D Laplacian by:

```
% 2D Laplacian, using gallery:
A2 = gallery('poisson', N);
```

Note that the size of $A_2$ is $N^2\times N^2$. Similarly, you can create a 3D discrete Laplacian ($N^3\times N^3$ matrix) by:

```
% 3D Laplacian:
A3 = kron(I,I,A1) + kron(I,A1,I) + kron(A1,I,I);
```

Now if you want to store a matrix, say, $A$, to a file, say, matrix.txt, you can do the following:

```
% Save A to a file
[i,j,a] = find(A);
matrix_data = [i,j,a];
save -ascii matrix.txt matrix_data
```

In the file, you find the triplets of the row and column indices and their associated matrix entry value on each line. You can read it simply in C++ and then do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: I´ve never used MatLab. But I´m going to try your code.

Comment: You can use Octave if you don't have access to Matlab, it's free. Except that Octave does not have the `gallery` command. Instead, you'd like to use the `spdiags` command to create the sparse tridiagonal matrix (`A1` in the code above). You can do it like: `A1=spdiags(ones(N,3)*diag([-1,2,-1]), -1:1, N, N)`.

Comment: But it will generate a matrix like this for example? ax + b = c. Becausa I also need the c value.

Comment: @DiegoMacario I don't understand at all your point. You said you wanted to generate a large SPD matrix (I still don't know if dense or sparse). If you want also the right hand side, then you can just pick any nonzero vector of the same size as the matrix (random, constant, etc.).

Comment: My teache told me that I need to use a matrix positive defined, I got from a book the expression tested in my code. So I understand that a I need the c value by the example in the book.

Comment: @DiegoMacario I don't understand, what do you mean by $c$.

Comment: x1+2x2 = 3, I got from the picture, this expression. A = x1, B = 2x2 and C = 3

Comment: Well, the system in your question can be written as $Ax=b$, where $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}$, $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$, and $b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}$. In one of the answers you can find how to generate an SPD matrix $A$, you also need a right-hand side $b$ to have a system to solve. So just pick some vector $b$ (e.g., random).

Comment: Ok, I didn´t know that I can put random values...In the B side

Comment: If you want to test the performance, it does not really matter. Convergence of the Jacobi method (if $A$ is, e.g., SPD) does not depend on the choice of the right-hand side but on the system matrix and possibly a relaxation parameter if you use some.